# Object not found in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I have got a problem using xampp. I hope u guys are able to solve it.

1. When i type in the address "localhost" it just shows "It works". But when i type "localhost/xampp" then it takes me to the welcome page of xampp. Why is that when everybody gets that just typing "localhost"?
2. I created a simple php hello world program to test under the folder htdocs and named it test.php. Then when i type in "localhost/xampp/test.php" it shows the message shown below-

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404 localhost 9/3/2013 2:23:28 AM Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2
>   mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1
>   mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

What should i do?

Answer (score 3):

Check if in httpd.conf file the DocumentRoot param is pointing to the folder htdocs.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but no where did I find a solution.
The solution is actually quite trivial, silly even :)

I wrote my hello world file in notepad and when saving I typed: 
test.php

but I failed to change the "save as type" option from "Text Document" to "All Files".

Yup, that's it and it worked!

I am assuming you have already found your solution.  I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

just simply set the path as http://
localhost/project_folder or file_name

**NOTE:**

no need to put http://
               localhost
               /xampp/htdocs/project_folder or file_name-**ERROR**