# Object Not Found and other issues in XAMPP in OSX

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I used to use installed Apache on my Mac to run php-files, but after updating to High Sierra my PHP already updated from v5 to v7. I've tried lots of hints but nothing worked. I've stopped the Apache server and installed XAMPP. It worked for the first time, but when I tried again for the second time it gave me 'Permission denied' error.
Then I've fixed it with httpd.conf and other manipulations. Now, when I click 'Go to application' it gives me this:
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

I checked and there are all necessary files (index.php, 2.php[my test]) in opt/lampp/htdocs, but this problem remained? Would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Can you take a look at this post, and see if the suggestions there work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580329/object-not-found-in-xampp

Comment: @OliverBaumann Yes, I've tried also this post, but didn't helped. DocumentRoot is right and other suggestions are also checked